# make a parent div clickable except for a child icon

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

```html
<div
  [ngClass]="{ 'template-row': !isExpandable, 'folder-row': isExpandable }"
  class="label-with-icons clickable"
  (click)="expanderClicked()"
  (click)="itemSelected()"
>
  <i *ngIf="isExpandable" [ngClass]="getArrowIconClass()"></i><i [ngClass]="getIconClass()"></i>
  <span *ngIf="id" class="name ">{{ name }}</span>
  <span *ngIf="!id" class="name">{{ name }}</span>

  <i *ngIf="!isExpandable" class="io-icon-trash clickable" id="delete" (click)="deleteTemplate()"></i>
</div>
```

I want the entire div to be clickable but not the icon with id= delete. I want to have a different click event on that
I dont use jquery , i work with TS

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: `#delete { pointer-evens: none } `

Comment: Easy workaround would be wrapping `<i><span><span>` in a separate `<div>` and add click events `(click)="expanderClicked() (click)="itemSelected()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop the event to propagate up in the DOM tree with `event.stopPropagation()` :

```
(click)="deleteTemplate($event)"></i>

deleteTemplate(e: Event) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // <----event won't travel up 
}
```